# Cannot connect to mongodb Error error occurred during connection

Tags: mongodb, go

im trying to connect to my mongodb from my api written in golang
but every time i run my app it gives me this error:

> 2022/12/06 19:09:25 server selection error: server selection timeout, current topology: { Type: ReplicaSetNoPrimary, Servers: [{ Addr: ac-tqorttq-shard-00-02.atpezds.mongodb.net:27017, Type: Unknown, Last error: connection() error occurred during connection handshake: dial tcp 52.28.222.2:27017: i/o timeout }, { Addr: ac-tqorttq-shard-00-00.atpezds.mongodb.net:27017, Type: Unknown, Last error: connection() error occurred during connection handshake: dial tcp 18.197.37.129:27017: i/o timeout }, { Addr: ac-tqorttq-shard-00-01.atpezds.mongodb.net:27017, Type: Unknown, Last error: connection() error occurred during connection handshake: dial tcp 18.195.134.220:27017: i/o timeout }, ] }

my code:

```golang
func init() {
    clientOptions := options.Client().ApplyURI(configs.GetEnv("MONGOURI"))

    client, err := mongo.Connect(context.TODO(), clientOptions)

    checkErr(err)

    err = client.Ping(context.TODO(), nil)

    checkErr(err)

    fmt.Println("connected to database successfully")

    notesCollection = openCollection("notes_collection")

    userCollection = openCollection("user_collection")

}
```

i tried to remove the "+srv" from the connection string then

it gives me this error:

> 2022/12/06 19:16:46 server selection error: server selection timeout, current topology: { Type: Unknown, Servers: [{ Addr: cluster0.atpezds.mongodb.net:27017, Type: Unknown, Last error: connection() error occurred during connection handshake: dial tcp: lookup cluster0.atpezds.mongodb.net: No address associated with hostname }, ] }

hope you guys help me
and thanks

Comment: You should provide the code where you try to make the connection. Otherwise your question will get closed

Comment: I have done that

Answer (score 0):

```
func main() {
    client, err := mongo.NewClient(options.Client().ApplyURI("<ATLAS_URI_HERE>"))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    ctx, _ := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)
    err = client.Connect(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer client.Disconnect(ctx)
    err = client.Ping(ctx, readpref.Primary())
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    databases, err := client.ListDatabaseNames(ctx, bson.M{})
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(databases)
}
```

Check that you are using the correct username and password for your database user, and that you are connecting to the correct database deployment. Check that you are specifying the correct authSource database in your connection string.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Hey Syed I tried what you said but now it gives me this error `server selection error: context deadline exceeded, current topology: { Type: ReplicaSetNoPrimary, Servers: [{ Addr: ac-tqorttq-shard-00-01.atpezds.mongodb.net:27017, Type: Unknown }, { Addr: ac-tqorttq-shard-00-02.atpezds.mongodb.net:27017, Type: Unknown }, { Addr: ac-tqorttq-shard-00-00.atpezds.mongodb.net:27017, Type: Unknown }, ] }`  and thank you for helping me

Comment: https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/quick-start-golang-mongodb-starting-and-setup I Suggest you to go to official document of the mongo DB